# SFTP to Azure Blob Store

Tags: azure, airflow, blobstore

I am trying to copy file from SFTP to Azure Blob store using SFTPToWasbOperator. I am getting error. It seems like I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. Could someone please check the following code and see if there is anything wrong with it?

***Airflow Logs***

**
[2022-07-10, 13:08:48 UTC] {sftp_to_wasb.py:188} INFO - Uploading /SPi_ESG_Live/07-04-2022/DataPoint_2022_07_04.csv to wasb://testcotainer as https://test.blob.core.windows.net/testcotainer/DataPoint_2022_07_04.csv

[2022-07-10, 13:08:48 UTC] {_universal.py:473} INFO - Request URL: 'https://.blob.core.windows.net/***/test/https%3A//test.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/DataPoint_2022_07_04.csv'

**Error msg**

"azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: URL has an invalid label."

***Airflow DAG***

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.operators.wasb_delete_blob import WasbDeleteBlobOperator
from airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.transfers.sftp_to_wasb import SFTPToWasbOperator
from airflow.providers.sftp.hooks.sftp import SFTPHook
from airflow.providers.sftp.operators.sftp import SFTPOperator

AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME = "testcotainer"
BLOB_PREFIX = "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/testcotainer/"
SFTP_SRC_PATH = "/SPi_test_Live/07-04-2022/"
ENV_ID = os.environ.get("SYSTEM_TESTS_ENV_ID")
DAG_ID = "example_sftp_to_wasb"


with DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),  # Override to match your needs
) as dag:
    # [START how_to_sftp_to_wasb]
    transfer_files_to_azure = SFTPToWasbOperator(
        task_id="transfer_files_from_sftp_to_wasb",
        # SFTP args
        sftp_source_path=SFTP_SRC_PATH,
        # AZURE args
        container_name=AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME,
        blob_prefix=BLOB_PREFIX,
    )
    # [END how_to_sftp_to_wasb]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with BLOB_PREFIX, its not a url its the prefix after the azure url

see this source example : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/_modules/tests/system/providers/microsoft/azure/example_sftp_to_wasb.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I am kind of new to Azure, do you know what the prefix should be?

Comment: Its the prefix  (like a relative path) in the url. It seems from the message that it should be "testcontainer" (not related to the container name)